# How to properly use a loop to find shortest route between multiple coordinates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-loops, path-finding

I have an array of objects each containing an x,y coordinate. I would like to calculate the shortest path between the objects in JavaScript.

The array of islands will also always be random so the route needs to be calculated dynamically.

I was unable to properly implement Dijkstra's algorithm in JavaScript. I have tried to use several path-finding algorithms from other languages and was unsuccessful.

Objects in array

```
var selected_islands= [{
   id: 0,
   name: "Island1",
   x: 212,
   y: 1271,
   size: 50,
}, {
   id: 1,
   name: "Island2",
   x: 495,
   y: 226,
   size: 15,
}, {
   id: 2,
   name: "Island3",
   x: 473,
   y: 832,
   size: 25,
}]
```

Run method on all Islands in array

```
 for (i in selected_islands) {
      duped = selected_islands[i].findClosestIsland(duped);
      console.log(duped);
   }
```

Inside my Island Class

```
compareDistance(island) {
      return this.pythagoreanTheorem(island.x, island.y);
   }

findClosestIsland(duped) {
      var lowest_val = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; // Setting high initial value
      for (i in duped) {
         if (this.compareDistance(selected_islands[i]) < lowest_val && this.compareDistance(selected_islands[i]) != 0) {
            lowest_val = this.compareDistance(selected_islands[i]);
            closest_island = selected_islands[i];
         }
      }
      duped.splice(0,1); // Immutable, ruins array
      return duped;
   }
```

splice method ruins my duplicate array. The logic is a bit fuzzy to me. Should I create a new array of "visited_islands" and loop through that every time?

[image: Canvas Output]

Thanks for any insight :)

Comment: How do you define a "path"? Can you move directly from coordinates (x1, y1) to (x2, y2)? Or is one island only connected to certain other islands? If so, your input will need to define these connections before you can proceed. Or do you need to instead visit every island? If so, then you need to use an algorithm for the Traveling Salesman, not for Shortest Path.

Comment: It is a direct path as the crow fly's no obstacle detection or anything yet. Its an arbitrary number of islands within a preset of 18 islands. So if 5 islands are selected I want to visit only those 5 islands in the shortest route. I looked into TSP seems it should work I am struggling to implement the code to fit mine.

Comment: @user2340824 I am not worried about that amount of precision quite yet. Size is used for hovering effects at the moment.

Comment: "So if 5 islands are selected I want to visit only those 5 islands in the shortest route." Yes, this is definitely the Traveling Salesman Problem, not Shortest Path like you started to implement. So Dijkstra's algorithm is not going to help.